# Apex: How to get all child element of an xml? - Parsing xml via XmlStreamReader

Tags: xml-parsing, salesforce, apex-code, apex, msxml

I am trying to parse an MSXML which is a response from a web services via XmlStreamReader.

The below code is the response from the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Report"> 
        <Table> 
            <Row> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project Name</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project Code</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Project URI Report Setting</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Entry Date</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Actual Billable Hours (Selected Dates)</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Actual Non-Billable Hours (Selected Dates)</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">User Name</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">User Default Billing Rate</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">User Default Billing Rate (BC)</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Timesheet Start Date</Data> 
                </Cell> 
                <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"> 
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Timesheet End Date</Data> 
                </Cell> 
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I wanted to get all the `cell(s)` in every ROW.

Here is my code on how do I parse the response *(assume that reportXML is the response)*:

```
 class Cell {
      string data { get; set; }
 }

 XmlStreamReader xsr = new XmlStreamReader(reportXML);

 while(xsr.hasNext()) {
      if (xsr.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT) {
           if (xsr.getLocalName() == 'Row') {
                Cell cell = parseCell(xsr);
                system.debug(cell);
           }
      }
      xsr.next();
 }

 Cell parseCell(XmlStreamReader reader) {
      Cell cell = new Cell();

      while(reader.hasNext()) {
           if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.END_ELEMENT) {
                break;
           }
           else if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) {
                cell.data = reader.getText();
           }

           reader.next();
      }

      return cell;
 }
```

The problem is I am only getting a single cell and not all the cell.
`Cell:[data=Project Name]` is the only data from the debug logs which I think the first column cell only.

Why? and what is the code that bugs the logic for displaying all cell data?

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. You want your `data` variable to be an array of `String` data type rather than a single `String`.
2. To avoid unpleasant surprises, it may be helpful to check that the `XmlTag.START_ELEMENT` is actually a `Cell`.
3. Once you define the `data` variable as an array, you can use the `add()` method to add each new String to the array (`cell.data.add( reader.getText() );`).